# Can'u use RelayCommand in XAML (not found)

Tags: c#, mvvm, relaycommand, maui-community-toolkit

I am building a MAUI app using Visual Studio 2022 (.NET 7.0) and the Community Toolkit for MVVM v8.2. I have created a RelayCommand in my viewmodel class:

```cs
public partial class LoginViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Login()
    { 
        // do stuff
    } 
}
```

And my XAML looks like this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiApp4.Views.LoginPage"
             Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False"
             Title="Login"
             BackgroundImageSource="background.jpg">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
           <Button
            Text="Login"
            WidthRequest="100" 
            CornerRadius="20" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center"
           Clicked="{Binding LoginCommand}"
        />
 </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

When I compile, I get this error:

```
XFC0009: No property, BindableProperty, or event found for "Clicked", or mismatching type between value and property.
```

This error seems to be indicating that there is no "Clicked" property or event, or that the type doesn't match. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no `Clicked` property in the shown code !! ... the error come from another place .... make sure where you use the `Clicked` property in your code To know the source of the problem

Comment: yeah sorry.. wrong code copied (updated) I've tried everything :( but obviously result is the same

Comment: use Command not Clicked

Comment: ALSO make sure you have the in the code behind constructor Dependency Injectioin or create the binding context.
  BindingContext = new LoginViewModel();

Comment: Use `command` instad of `clicked`

Answer (score 0):

using Command instead ofClicked solved all (this seems me a bit... unusual, coming from net winforms I've used to clicked event but... OK)

Comment: The `Button` in WPF does have a `Click` event but also a `Command` property. You can choose to use the event or the command, but not both together.

Comment: If you want to mark this question as "SOLVED" you have to accept an answer (it does not matter from whom, even yours).